# delete specific lines in txt file python

Tags: python, replace, file-io

so I have text file file.txt e.g

```
daemon

nserver 1111
nserver 11111
nscache 65536

timeouts 1 5 30 60 180 1800 15 60
log /var/log/3proxy/log D
logformat "- +_L%t.%. %N.%p %E %U %C:%c %R:%r %O %I %h %T"
logformat "L%t.%. %N.%p %E %U %C:%c %R:%r %Q:%q %O %I %h %T %n "

rotate 360
#external 0.0.0.0
#internal 0.0.0.0

auth strong
########################################################################## Ttest-for-dev ##########################################################################
users ttest-for-dev:CL:d4ec7bf6
allow login,ttest-for-dev
proxy -n -a -p8989 -i194.150.75.50 -e194.150.75.50
socks -n -a -p43434 -i194.150.75.50 -e194.150.75.50
flush
########################################################################## specuser ##########################################################################
users specuser:CL:d4ec7bf6
allow login,specuser
proxy -n -a -p8989 -i194.150.75.50 -e194.150.75.50
socks -n -a -p43434 -i194.150.75.50 -e194.150.75.50
flush

deny *

maxconn 254

setgid 65534
setuid 65534
```

now how can i remove the lines so that the following is left

So the output file will be

```
daemon

nserver 1111
nserver 11111
nscache 65536

timeouts 1 5 30 60 180 1800 15 60
log /var/log/3proxy/log D
logformat "- +_L%t.%. %N.%p %E %U %C:%c %R:%r %O %I %h %T"
logformat "L%t.%. %N.%p %E %U %C:%c %R:%r %Q:%q %O %I %h %T %n "

rotate 360
#external 0.0.0.0
#internal 0.0.0.0

auth strong
########################################################################## Ttest-for-dev ##########################################################################
users ttest-for-dev:CL:d4ec7bf6
allow login,ttest-for-dev
proxy -n -a -p8989 -i194.150.75.50 -e194.150.75.50
socks -n -a -p43434 -i194.150.75.50 -e194.150.75.50
flush

deny *

maxconn 254

setgid 65534
setuid 65534
```

Thank you

I have a script that adds lines, but I have no idea how to remake it to fit the conditions in the question

```
import sys

import fileinput


nameuser = "user1"
passuser = "pass1"

file_name = '/usr/local/etc/3proxy.cfg'
for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name,inplace=1):
    if 'auth strong' in line:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.replace(line, line+'\n########################################################################## '+ nameuser +' ##########################################################################'+'\nusers '+ nameuser +':CL:'+ psuser +'\nallow login,'+ nameuser +'\nflush')
    print (line, end='')
```

Comment: Could you explain the criteria for the lines to be deleted? Your code looks for `auth strong`, but I don't see any difference on that line.

Comment: There's always some options with these, but you could start by changing your if statement to include things that you don't want to include.

Comment: Your code doesn't delete anything. It just adds to a particular line. And if you're replacing the entire line, there's no need to use `replace()`, just use `line += "stuff to append"`

Comment: @Barmar I attached the output of the file in which the lines are being deleted. Before and after, you need to delete a few lines. The code example is taken from a script that adds, not removes. Described that I can’t figure out how to delete such lines

Comment: @Barmar

`########################################################################## specuser ##########################################################################
users specuser:CL:d4ec7bf6
allow login,specuser
proxy -n -a -p8989 -i194.150.75.50 -e194.150.75.50
socks -n -a -p43434 -i194.150.75.50 -e194.150.75.50
flush`
delete this lines

Comment: I know you attached it, but the difference doesn't stand out, are we all supposed to copy and paste into a file difference application to figure out what you want? Also, seeing one difference doesn't tell us what the general pattern is.

Comment: So you want to remove all lines that contain `specuser`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I'm sorry I didn't understand the question.

Comment: The second set of `proxy` and `socks` lines are also removed, but they don't contain `specuser`. So what's the actual criteria?

Comment: Is it everything from the first `###... specuser` line to the next blank line?

Comment: @Barmar This can be divided into two scripts. One removes `specuser`, the other removes `proxy and socks` + `flush` lines

Comment: @Barmar Is it everything from the first `###... specuser` line to `flush` and this `flush`

Comment: Question lacks prior research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file line by line. When you get to the `###... specuser` line, start a loop that keeps reading until the `flush` line. Otherwise, print the line.

```
import re

with fileinput.FileInput(file_name,inplace=1) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if re.match('#+ specuser #+$', line):
            for nextline in infile:
                if nextline.strip() == 'flush':
                    break
            continue
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: `if nextline.strip() == 'flush'
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` :(

Comment: `if re.match('#+ specuser #+$'):
TypeError: match() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'`, another error and after that the file is all empty, sorry for the inconvenience, but thank you very much for your help in this matter